# Difference between "Deployed "and "In Process" Campaign Status?

Tags: campaign

What is the difference between "Deployed "and "In Process" under status for campaigns?

Answer (score 0):

By default Campaign Status contains following values:

[image: Campaign status]

Other than those, any values has been added by your System Admin based on the business requirements.

Most possibly, "In Process" could be Campaigns which are still running and "Deployed" could be same as Completed.